# Magento 2 Grid Search Capabilities

Tags: magento2, module, grid, search

I have been asked to quote for a client who wants to have a standard Magento 2 grid in the backend for an extension I have custom built for them.

The want to be able to perform full-text searches, which I know how to do, but they want to be able to search fields that are in the database but not the grid.

For example:

They have a grid of blog posts in the backend. Each blog can contain links to products. The products are linked using a database table called `products_in_blog` and contains columns `blog_id` and `product_id`.

They want to be able to search for products in the blog admin area and return blogs that contain these products in the blog grid.

I don't necessarily need to know *exactly* how to do it as I can figure it out when it comes to the build. I just need to know if it is possible to do in order to provide a quote.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe You show those assigned blogs in product edit tab section?

Comment: I can see why that would be easier but, unfortunately, the client is pretty adamant that this is how the functionality is to be